# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: amazon-elasticache

I am installing the ElastiCache Cluster Client for PHP on Red Hat 7.2 and centos 6.5 Amazon AMI , but issue still same on all.

```
cat /etc/os-release    
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.2 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.2"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.2:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"    
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.2
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.2"


after install elastcache cluster  cleint for php i got this error 

php -v

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library    '/etc/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/amazon-elasticache-cluster-   client.so' - libsasl2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or       directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.15 (cli)
```

i have installed php by compiling/configure.
please let me know how to get out from this error, i tried everything but issue still same.

Answer (score 2):

On some systems, notably CentOS7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.1, libsasl2.so.3 has replaced libsasl2.so.2. On those systems, when you load the ElastiCache cluster client, it attempts and fails to find and load libsasl2.so.2. To resolve this issue, create a symbolic link to libsasl2.so.3 so that when the client attempts to load libsasl2.so.2, it is redirected to libsasl2.so.3. The following code creates this symbolic link.

```
cd /usr/lib64
sudo ln libsasl2.so.3 libsasl2.so.2
```

Source: From AWS documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.Installing.html